# NSComboBox to display unique items from a coredata entity binding of a property

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nscombobox

I have a typical Mac CoreData application which displays my entities in an `NSTableView` with an `NSArrayController`, and a panel on the right to edit/display the currently selected item in the `NSTableView`. I have an `Entity` (Pigeon) with an `NSString` property (colour) being displayed in an `NSComboBox`, so that the user can enter their own string for the colour or select a previously chosen colour from the drop down list. This is done by binding the Content Values of the `NSComboBox` to `Pigeons.arrangedObjects.colour`. This is sooooooo close to what I want, but because it's an array (and not a set) of all the colours that exist for the pigeons, duplicate values are listed in the drop down list of the `NSComboBox`. So if for example Blue is entered for the colour for one Pigeon, and it's also selected for a second Pigeon, then Blue is shown in the list twice.

Is there someway, somehow I can filter this to remove duplicate values? I've tried making a second `NSArrayController` which is bound to the `Pigeons.arrangedObjects.colour` and setting an `NSPredicate` to filter it, but I can't seem to figure out an `NSPredicate` for filtering out duplicate values. I want to use bindings for the values of the colours, so that as the application is running, if a colour is added or deleted (maybe a mistake was made in entering a colour), then the drop down list is updated to only have the currently entered colour values for Pigeons.

What is the best way to not showing these duplicate values?

Comment: +1 for the stubborn refusal to use the Americanised `color` in your code :-)

Comment: :D I had thought of changing it to `color` just for asking the question and decided that was stupid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on my phone and a little lazy, but I think you are looking for a keypath that looks like: @"@distinctunionofobects.someproperty"... Or google keypath operators.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better idea. I deleted my answer. The keypath operator is `@distinctUnionOfObjects`, so you'd use `Pigeons.arrangedObjects.@distinctUnionOfObjects.colour`.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Thanks Rob for stating exactly how to use  `@distinctUnionOfObjects`.